# Extract all possible values of AR column in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Several models in yii2 are bound to a database using ActiveRecords. I now want to have a list of all ids of this model. Say, all user IDs when the Model is called User.

Sure I could just fetch all models and iterate over them, much like

```
$ids = [];
$users = User::find()->all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $ids[] = $user->id;
}
```

But I feel there should be an easier way... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay in ActiveRecord then this accomplishes the same thing:

```
$ids = User::find()->select('id')->column();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This returns array:

```
$ids = (new \yii\db\Query)->select('id')->from(User::tableName())->all();
```